# Cannot login to Kubuntu after upgrading to 17.04 from 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kubuntu, login, 17.04

I am a Linux beginner, so please forgive mistakes and help me with easy explanations. I just upgraded Kubuntu on my Lenovo T440s Laptop to the current version, using do-release-upgrade. I am 95% sure, it had version 14.04 installed before. After the upgrade had finished, I rebooted the system and boot would pass the Kubuntu Logo (on black surface) but no further. It just shows a black screen. Now, I figured that if I type alt+F4, I enter terminal mode in which I can sign in and execute commands. By incident (after doing some research without success) I typed 'sudo lightdm' and the OLD plasma login screen appeared. I used it  to log in and after that found the new plasma surface with my widgets gone (no big deal) but my old data and software there. But it did not find wifi and even after pluging it to an ethernet cable, could not connect to the internet. 
After rebooting the login issues showed up again.

Appreciate your help.. Thanks!

Comment: If you have access to your personal data, do a backup and clean install.